# Arduino Due: multiple TCS sensors

Tags: programming, sensors, arduino-due, processing-lang

I am trying to run 2 `TCS3200`’s from one `Arduino Due`. Next, I must increase to 4 sensors. I need to read the data from the 2 digital pins but how do I read both within the same loop rather than in series to save time. The code reading one sensor tasoOutPin1 (pin 10) works but why can’t I place the second read command `int detectColor(int taosOutPin2)` before the `{` symbol?

```
int detectColor(int taosOutPin1) {

float white1 = colorRead(taosOutPin1,0,1);
float red1 = colorRead(taosOutPin1,1,1);
float blue1 = colorRead(taosOutPin1,2,1);
float green1 = colorRead(taosOutPin1,3,1);
}
```

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: What happens when you place the second / third / fourth read in?  Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't provide enough information for us to help you and you didn't respond to the request for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have to run these serially, but not sure why it's an issue, a due is quick.

seems more programming related... 'detectColor' is a function, and this is run inside the loop i assume.

```
int taosOutPin1 = 10; //color detector 1
int taosOutPin2 = 2; //Pins are examples, change to actual pin...
int taosOutPin3 = 3;
int taosOutPin4 = 4; //color detector 4

typedef struct {
   float white;
   float red;
   float blue;
   float green;

} color; 

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}


void loop() {

color detectedColorForSensor1 = detectColor(taosOutPin1);
color detectedColorForSensor2 = detectColor(taosOutPin2);
color detectedColorForSensor3 = detectColor(taosOutPin3);
color detectedColorForSensor4 = detectColor(taosOutPin4);

Serial.print(detectedColorForSensor1.red);
Serial.print(detectedColorForSensor1.green);
Serial.print(detectedColorForSensor1.blue);
Serial.print(detectedColorForSensor1.white);

//etc for sensor 2,3,4............


}

color detectColor(int taosOutPin1) {

color detectedColor;

detectedColor.white = colorRead(taosOutPin1,0,1);
detectedColor.red = colorRead(taosOutPin1,1,1);
detectedColor.blue = colorRead(taosOutPin1,2,1);
detectedColor.green = colorRead(taosOutPin1,3,1);

return detectedColor;

}
```